# Shiny App works locally, disconnected from server when deployed globally

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that works fine when I run it on my own computer, but fails to deploy properly via shinyapps. Every time I deploy the app it turns grey and says 'Disconnected from server'. Here is the output from showLogs(), but I'm a bit confused as to how to interpret it. I don't know why it is having trouble installing some packages. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317725+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      9: tryCatchList
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317725+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      8: tryCatch
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317726+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      7: connect$retry
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317726+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      6: eval
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317729+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      3: eval
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317729+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      2: eval.parent
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317729+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      1: local
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317912+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Error in install.packages(pkgs = x, repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") : 
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317914+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:   unable to install packages
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317727+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      5: eval
2016-07-29T21:02:49.317727+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      4: eval
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315087+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Server version: 0.4.5.2170
2016-08-01T14:50:49.470258+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Starting R with process ID: '17'
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315120+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: R version: 3.3.0
2016-08-01T14:50:49.486190+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: 
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315122+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: shiny version: 0.13.2
2016-08-01T14:50:49.486192+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:38250
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315126+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: rmarkdown version: NA
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315138+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: knitr version: NA
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315173+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: jsonlite version: 1.0
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315206+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: RJSONIO version: NA
2016-08-01T14:50:49.315226+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: htmltools version: 0.3.5
2016-08-01T14:50:49.464757+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2016-08-01T14:50:49.470256+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: 
2016-08-01T14:50:52.097553+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Loading required package: twitteR
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107937+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     50: PrepareTwitter [/srv/connect/apps/Other-app/server.R#14]
2016-08-01T14:50:52.108128+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:   unable to install packages
2016-08-01T14:50:52.098304+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107937+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     51: EnsurePackage [/srv/connect/apps/Other-app/server.R#6]
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107942+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      4: eval
2016-08-01T14:50:52.098305+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:   there is no package called ‘twitteR’
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107936+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     52: install.packages
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107942+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      3: eval
2016-08-01T14:50:52.100256+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107940+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      7: connect$retry
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107942+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      2: eval.parent
2016-08-01T14:50:52.100257+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107935+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107941+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      5: eval
2016-08-01T14:50:52.100629+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Warning in install.packages(pkgs = x, repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") :
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107938+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     13: runApp
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107939+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     11: doTryCatch
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107943+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      1: local
2016-08-01T14:50:52.100630+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107938+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     12: fn
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107939+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:     10: tryCatchOne
2016-08-01T14:50:52.108126+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Error in install.packages(pkgs = x, repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") : 
2016-08-01T14:50:52.101513+00:00 shinyapps[115742]: Warning: Error in install.packages: unable to install packages
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107941+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      6: eval
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107939+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      9: tryCatchList
2016-08-01T14:50:52.107940+00:00 shinyapps[115742]:      8: tryCatch}
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Start an R session and install any required packages from your application with install.packages().  Then, stop/stat your shiny server.

Hope it helps.